# initializing an object with a method other than constructer

Tags: java

I am a newbie in Java and programming.

I am trying to initialize an object with an already existing object.

Can i do that or do I need to use `new`?

In here i did'nt use `new`, but it worked, why?

I thought I need to instantiate an object using `new` before creating in memory.

In the code I initialized the `obj2` with `obj`, so if I print it is supposed to print `20`, but it is giving default value `30`.

I saw this code in android tutorial it says this `sharedpreferences obj = getsharedpreferences();` and thats when I got this doubt.

Can anyone clarify this?

```
public class Class1 {

    public int b=30;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Class1 ob =new Class1();
        ob.just();

    }

    public Class1 getobj()
    {
        Class1 obj =new Class1(b);

        return obj;
    }

    public void aamethod()
    {
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    void just()
    {
        Class1 obj2= getobj();
        System.out.println(obj2.b);
        obj2.aamethod();
    }

    Class1()
    {
        a=10;
    }

    Class1(int b)
    {
        b=20;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking at android tutorials? This is purely Java code

Comment: This won't even compile

Answer (score 1):

It's all about how the variables are a scoped. In that last class definition  where you set b=20. You are setting the value of b that was passed into the constructer to 20. If you change it to this.b = 20 it will change the public int b declared at the top of the class to 20 and as a result should print out 20. In that case though there is no point passing b into the constructer.

Variable assignment in constructors typically looks like

```
public int b 

public Class1 (int b) {
    this.b = b;
}
```

Where this.b is the globally scoped public int b at the top of the class and b is the constructor arg locally scoped to the constructer. If you have variables with the same name you need to differentiate which scope they are in, otherwise use a different name.